# Pokemon GO account sharing

Tags: pokemon-go

If you have your on account that you play on, but if your friend encounters a rare pokemon like a lapras on his account, that he can log on to my account and catch it for me and then log out. This way the rare pokemons are more accessible.

Is this allowed? If not, what is the punishment, if any.

Comment: you may get a soft ban for teleporting, this will result in you being unable to catch anything for a while.

Comment: In Ingress (Niantic's previous AR game), this sort of behaviour would have you "soft-banned" for a day or more; you could log in and do a very limited set of things in the game, but most actions you tried to take would have no effect. Besides which, doesn't this strike you as cheating? Are you That Player?

Comment: Do that a couple of times and you'll face a permanent ban.

Answer (score 2):

Niantic has a strict one account equals one human rule. If you were to violate this rule (for example, sharing your password), you would risk having your account permanently banned for sharing it.

Additionally, your account would seem to have "teleported" to a location that you're likely nowhere near. This will also act as a red flag on your account, and may result in a ban.